# send NSMutableArray from ViewController to Sprite Kit View

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, send, sprite-kit

I am able to send a NSMutableArray between view controllers but when I try to use the same method from a ViewController to Sprite Kit View it does not work. I believe one of the reasons my be that when attempting to use this line:

```
playViewController *mainScreen = [[playViewController alloc ]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

This line is needed for the sending of NSMutableArrays but if I try to use it with a SKView it only allows:

```
BuildScene *second = [BuildScene alloc];
```

Any suggestions on what to do? Thank you in advance!

Comment: where are you sending the array.?

Comment: Your examples don't shed much light on how that array would be sent. And you need to send an `init` message to your `BuildScene` method as well.

Comment: You wouldn't need to send it. You need to get ahold of a reference of your custom view or view controller subclass, then assign the array to a NSMutableArray property you've added to your custom view/controller.

Answer (score 0):

In your BuildScene's .h file, declare a method:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* data;

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size andData:(NSMutableArray*)data;
```

In your .m file, implement the method:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size andData:(NSMutableArray*)data
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
          self.data = data;
    }
}
```

And then, from your viewController,

```
BuildScene *second = [[BuildScene alloc]initWithSize:CGSizeMake(768, 1024) andData:data];
```